# how to use Python relativedelta(or other ways) calculate 'Date after Months' in this dataframe?

Tags: python, date, multiple-columns, calculated-columns, relativedelta

<How to calcurate Date after months?>
[Date after months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DM1V.png)

```
|Date       |months |Date after months|
|12/31/2021 |128    |
|1/11/2022  |5      |
|10/2/2020  |67     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: it looks like there is a bug in `DateOffset` (`12/31/2021` + 128 months is giving `08/28/2032` incorrectly) when applied on a Series, see the alternative for a workaround.*

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use a [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
df['Date after months'] = (pd
 .to_datetime(df['Date'])
 .add(pd.DateOffset(months=1)*df['months'])
 .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
)
```

Output:

```
         Date  months Date after months
0  12/31/2021     128        08/28/2032
1   1/11/2022       5        06/11/2022
2   10/2/2020      67        05/02/2026
```

##### alternative

```
df['Date after months'] = (pd
  .Series([d+pd.DateOffset(months=x)
           for d, x in zip(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']), df['months'])],
          index=df.index)
  .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
 )
```

```
         Date  months Date after months
0  12/31/2021     128        08/31/2032
1   1/11/2022       5        06/11/2022
2   10/2/2020      67        05/02/2026
```